# shapely says polygons is not contained within another

Tags: python, matplotlib, polygon, shapely

I have two polygons, and I am trying to use shapely to tell me if one polygon touches another polygon.

Here is the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import shapely
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    a = shapely.geometry.Polygon((
        (239948.84366885605,6247904.745529621),(238281.02710020886,6250794.291071406),
        (238693.67295395266,6251899.199182685),(238292.52776364237,6253065.862501571),
        (239369.8867152306,6255078.983834209),(241149.62036734243,6258808.484109194),
        (246601.12030818601,6254149.774368979),(247369.5081433506,6252263.219573404),
        (246378.77811632192,6251486.8296787),(246522.3713691934,6251301.933776115),
        (245312.5127001227,6249410.396470293),(243242.96423660984,6248751.24094899),
        (239948.84366885605,6247904.745529621)
    ))
    b = shapely.geometry.Polygon((
        (243324,6254378),(243324,6254378),(243330,6254383),(243330,6254383),(243324,6254378)
    ))

    print(a.contains(b))
    print(a.intersects(b))
    print(a.overlaps(b))

    plt.plot(*a.exterior.xy, c='red')
    plt.plot(*b.exterior.xy, c='green')
    plt.gca().axis("equal")
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It outputs :

```
False
False
False
```

and yet we can see on the drawn image that polygon b is indeed within polygon a :

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39NpQ.jpg)

I am expecting polygon b to be within polygon a, and thus this program to output :

```
True
True
True
```

Comment: Probably not the cause, but `(239948.84366885605,6247904.745529621)` why do the values for polygon `a` have such long numbers after the decimal point?

Comment: The second polygon has null area, it collapses to just a segment, is that what you want?

Comment: @JohnGordon it is a polygon i am using for a project, from public data.
blunova yes, same for the first one i did not directly create this polygon !

Answer (score 0):

After reading @blunova's comment, it seems that having a polygon with a zero area is the problem.

I added

```
b = b.buffer(0.01)
```

And now it works!